# Range is not defined in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, cdn, alpine.js

[image]

After linking the alpine.js with the html it was expected to work as usual. but in the console it is showing those 2 error as `index not defined` and `range not defined`

Answer (score 2):

It's needed the **defer** attribute to load fine the alpine script:

```
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
```